# Таймер JS. Как сделать задержку перед началом работы функции

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Не получается реализовать задержку перед запуском функции (таймера), пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы функция была запущена через 60 секунд после загрузки страницы. Проще говоря, установить определенное время для запуска таймера после загрузки страницы. Сам таймер имеет два кода на JS, прикрепил снизу. 
Заранее спасибо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
;
(function($, window, document, undefined) {
  var pluginName = "countdown360",
    defaults = {
      radius: 15.5, // radius of arc
      strokeStyle: "#0081d7", // the color of the stroke
      strokeWidth: 5, // the stroke width, dynamically calulated if omitted in options
      fillStyle: "#004388", // the fill color
      fontColor: "#477050", // the font color
      fontFamily: "sans-serif", // the font family
      fontSize: 15, // the font size, dynamically calulated if omitted in options
      fontWeight: 200, // the font weight
      autostart: false, // start the countdown automatically
      seconds: 10, // the number of seconds to count down
      label: ["second", "seconds"], // the label to use or false if none
      startOverAfterAdding: true, // Start the timer over after time is added with addSeconds
      smooth: false, // should the timer be smooth or stepping
      onComplete: function() {}
    };

  function Plugin(element, options) {
    this.element = element;
    this.settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
    if (!this.settings.fontSize) {
      this.settings.fontSize = this.settings.radius / 1.2;
    }
    if (!this.settings.strokeWidth) {
      this.settings.strokeWidth = this.settings.radius / 4;
    }
    this._defaults = defaults;
    this._name = pluginName;
    this._init();
  }

  Plugin.prototype = {
    getTimeRemaining: function() {

      var timeRemaining = this._secondsLeft(this.getElapsedTime());
      return timeRemaining;
    },
    getElapsedTime: function() {
      return Math.round((new Date().getTime() - this.startedAt.getTime()) / 1000);
    },
    extendTimer: function(value) {
      var seconds = parseInt(value),
        secondsElapsed = Math.round((new Date().getTime() - this.startedAt.getTime()) / 1000);
      if ((this._secondsLeft(secondsElapsed) + seconds) <= this.settings.seconds) {
        this.startedAt.setSeconds(this.startedAt.getSeconds() + parseInt(value));
      }
    },

    addSeconds: function(value) {
      var secondsElapsed = Math.round((new Date().getTime() - this.startedAt.getTime()) / 1000);
      if (this.settings.startOverAfterAdding) {
        this.settings.seconds = this._secondsLeft(secondsElapsed) + parseInt(value);
        this.start();
      } else {
        this.settings.seconds += parseInt(value);
      }
    },

    start: function() {
      this.startedAt = new Date();
      this._drawCountdownShape(Math.PI * 3.5, true);
      this._drawCountdownLabel(0);
      var timerInterval = 1000;
      if (this.settings.smooth) {
        timerInterval = 16;
      }
      this.interval = setInterval(jQuery.proxy(this._draw, this), timerInterval);
    },

    stop: function(cb) {
      clearInterval(this.interval);
      if (cb) {
        cb();
      }
    },

    _init: function() {
      this.settings.width = (this.settings.radius * 2) + (this.settings.strokeWidth * 2);
      this.settings.height = this.settings.width;
      this.settings.arcX = this.settings.radius + this.settings.strokeWidth;
      this.settings.arcY = this.settings.arcX;
      this._initPen(this._getCanvas());
      if (this.settings.autostart) {
        this.start();
      }
    },

    _getCanvas: function() {
      var $canvas = $("<canvas id=\"countdown360_" + $(this.element).attr("id") + "\" width=\"" +
        this.settings.width + "\" height=\"" +
        this.settings.height + "\">" +
        "<span id=\"countdown-text\" role=\"status\" aria-live=\"assertive\"></span></canvas>");
      $(this.element).prepend($canvas[0]);
      return $canvas[0];
    },

    _initPen: function(canvas) {
      this.pen = canvas.getContext("2d");
      this.pen.lineWidth = this.settings.strokeWidth;
      this.pen.strokeStyle = this.settings.strokeStyle;
      this.pen.fillStyle = this.settings.fillStyle;
      this.pen.textAlign = "center";
      this.pen.textBaseline = "middle";
      this.ariaText = $(canvas).children("#countdown-text");
      this._clearRect();
    },

    _clearRect: function() {
      this.pen.clearRect(0, 0, this.settings.width, this.settings.height);
    },

    _secondsLeft: function(secondsElapsed) {
      return this.settings.seconds - secondsElapsed;
    },

    _drawCountdownLabel: function(secondsElapsed) {
      this.ariaText.text(secondsLeft);
      this.pen.font = this.settings.fontWeight + " " + this.settings.fontSize + "px " + this.settings.fontFamily;
      var secondsLeft = this._secondsLeft(secondsElapsed),
        label = secondsLeft === 1 ? this.settings.label[0] : this.settings.label[1],
        drawLabel = this.settings.label && this.settings.label.length === 2,
        x = this.settings.width / 2;
      if (drawLabel) {
        y = this.settings.height / 2 - (this.settings.fontSize / 6.2);
      } else {
        y = this.settings.height / 2;
      }
      this.pen.fillStyle = this.settings.fillStyle;
      this.pen.fillText(secondsLeft + 1, x, y);
      this.pen.fillStyle = this.settings.fontColor;
      this.pen.fillText(secondsLeft, x, y);
      if (drawLabel) {
        this.pen.font = "normal small-caps " + (this.settings.fontSize / 3) + "px " + this.settings.fontFamily;
        this.pen.fillText(label, this.settings.width / 2, this.settings.height / 2 + (this.settings.fontSize / 0.0));
      }
    },

    _drawCountdownShape: function(endAngle, drawStroke) {
      this.pen.fillStyle = this.settings.fillStyle;
      this.pen.beginPath();
      this.pen.arc(this.settings.arcX, this.settings.arcY, this.settings.radius, Math.PI * 1.5, endAngle, false);
      this.pen.fill();
      if (drawStroke) {
        this.pen.stroke();
      }
    },

    _draw: function() {
      var millisElapsed, secondsElapsed;
      millisElapsed = new Date().getTime() - this.startedAt.getTime();
      secondsElapsed = Math.floor((millisElapsed) / 1000);
      endAngle = (Math.PI * 3.5) - (((Math.PI * 2) / (this.settings.seconds * 1000)) * millisElapsed);
      this._clearRect();
      this._drawCountdownShape(Math.PI * 3.5, false);
      if (secondsElapsed < this.settings.seconds) {
        this._drawCountdownShape(endAngle, true);
        this._drawCountdownLabel(secondsElapsed);
      } else {
        this._drawCountdownLabel(this.settings.seconds);
        this.stop();
        this.settings.onComplete();
      }
    }

  };

  $.fn[pluginName] = function(options) {
    var plugin;
    this.each(function() {
      plugin = $.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName);
      if (!plugin) {
        plugin = new Plugin(this, options);
        $.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName, plugin);
      }
    });
    return plugin;
  };

})(jQuery, window, document);

var countdown = $("#countdown").countdown360({
  radius: 20,
  seconds: 60,
  fontColor: '#ffffff',
  autostart: false,
  onComplete: function() {
    console.log('done')
  }
});

countdown.start();
$(document).on("click", "button", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var type = $(this).attr("data-type");
  if (type === "time-remaining")

  {
    var timeRemaining = countdown.getTimeRemaining();

  } else {
    var timeElapsed = countdown.getElapsedTime();

  }
});

var countdown = $("#countdown2").countdown360({
  radius: 20,
  seconds: 60,
  fontColor: '#ffffff',

  autostart: false,
  onComplete: function() {
    console.log('done')
  }
});
countdown.start();
$(document).on("click", "button", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var type = $(this).attr("data-type");
  if (type === "time-remaining") {
    var timeRemaining = countdown.getTimeRemaining();

  } else {
    var timeElapsed = countdown.getElapsedTime();

  }
});
var countdown = $("#countdown3").countdown360({
  radius: 20,
  seconds: 60,
  fontColor: '#ffffff',

  autostart: false,
  onComplete: function() {
    console.log('done')
  }
});
countdown.start();
$(document).on("click", "button", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var type = $(this).attr("data-type");
  if (type === "time-remaining") {
    var timeRemaining = countdown.getTimeRemaining();

  } else {
    var timeElapsed = countdown.getElapsedTime();

  }
});
var countdown = $("#countdown4").countdown360({
  radius: 20,
  seconds: 60,
  fontColor: '#ffffff',

  autostart: false,
  onComplete: function() {
    console.log('done')
  }
});
countdown.start();
$(document).on("click", "button", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var type = $(this).attr("data-type");
  if (type === "time-remaining") {
    var timeRemaining = countdown.getTimeRemaining();

  } else {
    var timeElapsed = countdown.getElapsedTime();

  }
});
var countdown = $("#countdown5").countdown360({
  radius: 20,
  seconds: 60,
  fontColor: '#ffffff',

  autostart: false,
  onComplete: function() {
    console.log('done')
  }
});
countdown.start();
$(document).on("click", "button", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var type = $(this).attr("data-type");
  if (type === "time-remaining") {
    var timeRemaining = countdown.getTimeRemaining();

  } else {
    var timeElapsed = countdown.getElapsedTime();

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.css">
<script src="https://cdn.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.webrtc-experiment.com/gif-recorder.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.webrtc-experiment.com/gumadapter.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.webrtc-experiment.com/DetectRTC.js">
</script>
<script src="https://cvingcam.000webhostapp.com/CVINGWeb/src/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table>

  <tr id="0" style="height: 68px; border-bottom: 1px solid #255791;">
    <td onclick="setVideo(0)" align="center" style="cursor: pointer; font-size: 16px; padding-left: 75px">What can you tell me about yourself?</td>
    <td align="center" width="75px" style="margin-right: 25px">
      <div id="countdown"></div>
    </td>
    <td align="center" width="75px" style="margin-right: 25px">
      <div class="checkmark-circle" id="firstArrow" style="display:none">
        <div class="background"></div>
        <div class="checkmark draw"></div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="1" style="height: 68px;border-bottom: 1px solid #255791;">
    <td onclick="setVideo(1)" align="center" style="cursor: pointer; font-size: 16px; padding-left: 75px">Can you list your strengths?</td>
    <td align="center" width="75px" style="margin-right: 25px">
      <div id="countdown2"></div>
    </td>
    <td align="center" width="75px" style="margin-right: 25px">
      <div class="checkmark-circle" id="secondArrow" style="display:none">
        <div class="background"></div>
        <div class="checkmark draw"></div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="2" style="height: 68px; border-bottom: 1px solid #255791;">
    <td onclick="setVideo(2)" align="center" style="cursor: pointer; font-size: 16px; padding-left: 75px">What weaknesses do you have?</td>
    <td align="center" width="75px" style="margin-right: 25px">
      <div id="countdown3"></div>
    </td>
    <td align="center" width="75px" style="margin-right: 25px">
      <div class="checkmark-circle" id="thirdArrow" style="display:none">
        <div class="background"></div>
        <div class="checkmark draw"></div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="3" style="height: 68px; border-bottom: 1px solid #255791;">
    <td onclick="setVideo(3)" align="center" style="cursor: pointer; font-size: 16px; padding-left: 75px">Where do you see yourself five years from now?</td>
    <td align="center" width="75px" style="margin-right: 25px">
      <div id="countdown4"></div>
    </td>
    <td align="center" width="75px" style="margin-right: 25px">
      <div class="checkmark-circle" id="fourthArrow" style="display:none">
        <div class="background"></div>
        <div class="checkmark draw"></div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="4" style="height: 66px; ">
    <td onclick="setVideo(4)" align="center" style="cursor: pointer; font-size: 16px; padding-left: 75px">Why do you want to work here?</td>
    <td align="center" width="75px" style="margin-right: 25px">
      <div id="countdown5"></div>
    </td>
    <td align="center" width="75px" style="margin-right: 25px">
      <div class="checkmark-circle" id="fifthArrow" style="display:none">
        <div class="background"></div>
        <div class="checkmark draw"></div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Добавьте html и css, чтобы можно было воспроизвестип проблему. И где код, где вы пытаетесь задать задержку?

Comment: Ссылка на сайт решению проблемы не поможет. И почему это вы не можете весь код сюда подключить!

Comment: @Cheg вставил, теперь все работает в коде. извините за криворукость.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько понял из вопроса, вам нужно запускать каждый последующий таймер посел окончания предыдущего. Для этого не обязательно объявлять каждый таймер отдельно. Достаточно вынести настройки таймера в отдельную переменную, добавить счетчик таймеров и вызывать каждый последующий таймер в `callback`'е предыдущего - у данного плагина он называется `onComplete()`.

В данном примере важно, чтобы таймеры были пронумерованы, начиная с 1, и каждому таймеру был прописан класс `.countdown` (для определения кол0ва таймеров):

```js
;
(function($, window, document, undefined) {
  var pluginName = "countdown360",
    defaults = {
      radius: 15.5, // radius of arc
      strokeStyle: "#0081d7", // the color of the stroke
      strokeWidth: 5, // the stroke width, dynamically calulated if omitted in options
      fillStyle: "#004388", // the fill color
      fontColor: "#477050", // the font color
      fontFamily: "sans-serif", // the font family
      fontSize: 15, // the font size, dynamically calulated if omitted in options
      fontWeight: 200, // the font weight
      autostart: false, // start the countdown automatically
      seconds: 10, // the number of seconds to count down
      label: ["second", "seconds"], // the label to use or false if none
      startOverAfterAdding: true, // Start the timer over after time is added with addSeconds
      smooth: false, // should the timer be smooth or stepping
      onComplete: function() {}
    };

  function Plugin(element, options) {
    this.element = element;
    this.settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
    if (!this.settings.fontSize) {
      this.settings.fontSize = this.settings.radius / 1.2;
    }
    if (!this.settings.strokeWidth) {
      this.settings.strokeWidth = this.settings.radius / 4;
    }
    this._defaults = defaults;
    this._name = pluginName;
    this._init();
  }

  Plugin.prototype = {
    getTimeRemaining: function() {

      var timeRemaining = this._secondsLeft(this.getElapsedTime());
      return timeRemaining;
    },
    getElapsedTime: function() {
      return Math.round((new Date().getTime() - this.startedAt.getTime()) / 1000);
    },
    extendTimer: function(value) {
      var seconds = parseInt(value),
        secondsElapsed = Math.round((new Date().getTime() - this.startedAt.getTime()) / 1000);
      if ((this._secondsLeft(secondsElapsed) + seconds) <= this.settings.seconds) {
        this.startedAt.setSeconds(this.startedAt.getSeconds() + parseInt(value));
      }
    },

    addSeconds: function(value) {
      var secondsElapsed = Math.round((new Date().getTime() - this.startedAt.getTime()) / 1000);
      if (this.settings.startOverAfterAdding) {
        this.settings.seconds = this._secondsLeft(secondsElapsed) + parseInt(value);
        this.start();
      } else {
        this.settings.seconds += parseInt(value);
      }
    },

    start: function() {
      this.startedAt = new Date();
      this._drawCountdownShape(Math.PI * 3.5, true);
      this._drawCountdownLabel(0);
      var timerInterval = 1000;
      if (this.settings.smooth) {
        timerInterval = 16;
      }
      this.interval = setInterval(jQuery.proxy(this._draw, this), timerInterval);
    },

    stop: function(cb) {
      clearInterval(this.interval);
      if (cb) {
        cb();
      }
    },

    _init: function() {
      this.settings.width = (this.settings.radius * 2) + (this.settings.strokeWidth * 2);
      this.settings.height = this.settings.width;
      this.settings.arcX = this.settings.radius + this.settings.strokeWidth;
      this.settings.arcY = this.settings.arcX;
      this._initPen(this._getCanvas());
      if (this.settings.autostart) {
        this.start();
      }
    },

    _getCanvas: function() {
      var $canvas = $("<canvas id=\"countdown360_" + $(this.element).attr("id") + "\" width=\"" +
        this.settings.width + "\" height=\"" +
        this.settings.height + "\">" +
        "<span id=\"countdown-text\" role=\"status\" aria-live=\"assertive\"></span></canvas>");
      $(this.element).prepend($canvas[0]);
      return $canvas[0];
    },

    _initPen: function(canvas) {
      this.pen = canvas.getContext("2d");
      this.pen.lineWidth = this.settings.strokeWidth;
      this.pen.strokeStyle = this.settings.strokeStyle;
      this.pen.fillStyle = this.settings.fillStyle;
      this.pen.textAlign = "center";
      this.pen.textBaseline = "middle";
      this.ariaText = $(canvas).children("#countdown-text");
      this._clearRect();
    },

    _clearRect: function() {
      this.pen.clearRect(0, 0, this.settings.width, this.settings.height);
    },

    _secondsLeft: function(secondsElapsed) {
      return this.settings.seconds - secondsElapsed;
    },

    _drawCountdownLabel: function(secondsElapsed) {
      this.ariaText.text(secondsLeft);
      this.pen.font = this.settings.fontWeight + " " + this.settings.fontSize + "px " + this.settings.fontFamily;
      var secondsLeft = this._secondsLeft(secondsElapsed),
        label = secondsLeft === 1 ? this.settings.label[0] : this.settings.label[1],
        drawLabel = this.settings.label && this.settings.label.length === 2,
        x = this.settings.width / 2;
      if (drawLabel) {
        y = this.settings.height / 2 - (this.settings.fontSize / 6.2);
      } else {
        y = this.settings.height / 2;
      }
      this.pen.fillStyle = this.settings.fillStyle;
      this.pen.fillText(secondsLeft + 1, x, y);
      this.pen.fillStyle = this.settings.fontColor;
      this.pen.fillText(secondsLeft, x, y);
      if (drawLabel) {
        this.pen.font = "normal small-caps " + (this.settings.fontSize / 3) + "px " + this.settings.fontFamily;
        this.pen.fillText(label, this.settings.width / 2, this.settings.height / 2 + (this.settings.fontSize / 0.0));
      }
    },

    _drawCountdownShape: function(endAngle, drawStroke) {
      this.pen.fillStyle = this.settings.fillStyle;
      this.pen.beginPath();
      this.pen.arc(this.settings.arcX, this.settings.arcY, this.settings.radius, Math.PI * 1.5, endAngle, false);
      this.pen.fill();
      if (drawStroke) {
        this.pen.stroke();
      }
    },

    _draw: function() {
      var millisElapsed, secondsElapsed;
      millisElapsed = new Date().getTime() - this.startedAt.getTime();
      secondsElapsed = Math.floor((millisElapsed) / 1000);
      endAngle = (Math.PI * 3.5) - (((Math.PI * 2) / (this.settings.seconds * 1000)) * millisElapsed);
      this._clearRect();
      this._drawCountdownShape(Math.PI * 3.5, false);
      if (secondsElapsed < this.settings.seconds) {
        this._drawCountdownShape(endAngle, true);
        this._drawCountdownLabel(secondsElapsed);
      } else {
        this._drawCountdownLabel(this.settings.seconds);
        this.stop();
        this.settings.onComplete();
      }
    }

  };

  $.fn[pluginName] = function(options) {
    var plugin;
    this.each(function() {
      plugin = $.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName);
      if (!plugin) {
        plugin = new Plugin(this, options);
        $.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName, plugin);
      }
    });
    return plugin;
  };

})(jQuery, window, document);

var cdLength = $('.countdown').length; // кол-во таймеров
var cdCount = 1; // счетчик таймеров
var cdOptions = { // настройки таймеров
  radius: 20,
  seconds: 5,
  fontColor: '#ffffff',
  autostart: true,
  onComplete: function() {
    console.log(cdCount + ' done');
    cdCount = cdCount + 1; // прибавляем к счетчику 1, чтобы получить следующий номер таймера
    if (cdCount <= cdLength) { // если номер таймера <= общему кол-ву таймеров
      $('#countdown' + cdCount).countdown360(cdOptions); // запускаем следующий таймер
    }
  }
};
$('#countdown' + cdCount).countdown360(cdOptions); // запуск первого таймера
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>

What can you tell me about yourself?
<div id="countdown1" class="countdown"></div>
Can you list your strengths?
<div id="countdown2" class="countdown"></div>
What weaknesses do you have?
<div id="countdown3" class="countdown"></div>
Where do you see yourself five years from now?
<div id="countdown4" class="countdown"></div>
Why do you want to work here?
<div id="countdown5" class="countdown"></div>
```

Comment: спасибо огромное, это как раз то что я и имел ввиду!

Answer (score 0):

можно создавать таймауты и очищать их когда функция закончит роботу

Comment: И для чего же их очищать, если они и так закончились?